# Find two integers b (one negative and one positive) such that 7 = b (mod 3)

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am a beginner trying to really grasp this concept. How should i go along to solving this?

Comment: Hint: $\ a \equiv -2a\pmod{3}\ \ $

Comment: A friendly advice: [title is NOT the first sentence of your question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/356647). In particular, see the last bullet: the question post should be comprehensible without the title, even though one should make good use of the title to provide extra info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a,b$ be integers such that $a \equiv b\text{ mod }n$. So,
$$a-b = nk$$
for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. If $a$ and $n$ are given, then you need to solve

> $$b = a- nk.$$

First, if you want $b > 0$, then $a - nk > 0$, or, $a > nk$.

In your case, $a = 7$ and $n = 3$. So, you need to solve
$$b=7-3k$$
where $7>3k$, or, $k < \frac{7}{3} < 3$. Thus, you can take $k=1$ or $2$ (any negative $k$ works too, as pointed out). Can you continue?

Comment: It's true that $k=1$ or $2$ satisify $k<7/3$, but there are many more $k\in\mathbb Z$ that do ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm of course! I wrote $k>0$ because is easy for beginners identidy